# Сумма чисел в файле python

Tags: python, python-3.x

В каждой строке  файла могут встречаться цифры и другие символы. Число -последовательность цифр, которая не может быть расширена до большего числа. При этом если перед числом стоит символ "-", то оно считается отрицательным.
Найти сумму всех чисел в этом файле.
**input.txt**
Sochi-2014
**output.txt** -2014

**input.txt**
a1b2c10d
**output.txt**
13

```
input = open('input.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
s = input.read()
l = len(s)
c = input.read(1)
sum2=0
x=0
sum1=[]
while l>0: 
        if c.isdigit!= 0:
                x+=int(c)#ошибка здесь
                sum1.append(x)
        c = input.read(1)
        l-=1
for i in range(len(sum1)):
        sum2+=sum1[i]
output.write(sum2)
input.close()
output.close()
```

Что нужно исправить? На данный момент в output.txt ничего не появляется

Comment: Дайте пример данных в файле

Comment: Как парсить `11.123` - это число `11.123` или два числа: `11` и `123`?

Comment: Это два числа..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Более приближённое к вашему варианту решение. Вам должно быть понятно. Так, как делаете вы - не очень хорошо. Очень много переменных, причём названия не очень понятные. Упрощайте.

И не надо называть переменные, как функции. Например, `input`, `sum`.

```
import re # импортируем модуль регулярных выражений

inp = open('input.txt', 'r')
out = open('output.txt', 'a')
summ = 0

numbers = inp.read() # читаем файл
numbers = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+', numbers) # находим все числа без/с префиксами + и -
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers] # приводим числа к типу int с помощью list comprehension

# суммируем числа
for x in numbers:
    summ += x

out.write(str(summ)) # записываем результат, обязательно в виде строки

# закрываем файлы
inp.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Зачем искать числа с префиксом + ?

Comment: @Alban просто для примера

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
Pattern = re.compile(r'-?\d+')
def foo(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as File:
        lst = [int(x) for x in re.findall(Pattern, File.read())]
    return sum(lst)
```

Использование:

```
print(foo(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DKOM-Rootkit-master\numbers.txt'))
```

В файл я положил:

```
a1b2c10d-15 -5.6
```

Результат:

```
-1
```

Еще вариант с `lambda` функцией:

```
In [18]: foo = lambda path: sum(map(int, re.findall(r'-?\d+', open(path).read())))

In [19]: foo(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DKOM-Rootkit-master\numbers.txt')
Out[19]: -1
```

Comment: А Вы не можете в исходном исправить?

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva боюсь там всё слишком запущено :(

Comment: Для файлов, которые целиком помещаются в память можно "one-liner" написать: `sum(int(x) for x in re.findall('(\-?\d+)', open(r'input.txt').read()))` ;-)

Comment: @MaxU Нужно больше читабельности :)